# Como utilizar o Google Maps com JSF

Tags: google-maps, jsf, jsf-2.2, primefaces

Preciso usar o Google Maps em uma aplicação JSF. O primefaces oferece o [GMap](http://www.mashups4jsf.com/gmaps4jsf-examples/home.jsf). Encontrei também o [GMaps4JSF](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/gmapHome.jsf). Qual das duas abordagens é a melhor, ou se existem outras, qual me trará mais benefícios ou mais flexibilidade?

**Referências**

http://www.mashups4jsf.com/gmaps4jsf-examples/home.jsf
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/gmapHome.jsf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se estiver desenvolvendo a aplicação para uma empresa que necessitará de constante suporte e atualizações, indico que use o Primefaces devido a grande comunidade em torno dele.

Se não for extremamente necessário esse suporte e atualizações, avalie quais são as necessidades da sua aplicação e escolha a opção que te atender melhor e com mais simplicidade.

Comment: Olá, @rocmartins. Na verdade, a aplicação é para uso em um trabalho de conclusão de curso. A minha dúvida é sobre as alternativas existentes de APIs que fazem essa integração JSF/Google Maps. Sou novato ainda no uso do JSF. O que sei é que não é recomendado o uso puro de JavaScript nas páginas JSF, ou  que se evite o uso abusivo do mesmo. Por isso não parti simplesmente para a documentação do Google Maps Api V3. Grato pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: O Primefaces é uma biblioteca de componentes JSF bem grande e com uma comunidade ativa que poderá te ajudar bastante nas dúvidas e problemas que tiver, acredito que seja uma boa opção para iniciar na tecnologia.

Quanto ao Javascript, realmente é necessário evitar o uso de Javascript em páginas JSF, pois os componentes JSF (como os componentes do Primefaces por exemplo) costumam utilizar bastante Javascript.